# changing font and color of text in table header - material table(0.19.4)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have started working with react and material ui and facing problem in changing the color and font of text in the table header. Over riding it doesn't seem to change the default style.It is specified that using "headerStyle"(object) changes the header styling. Can anyone help me with properties that has to be changed to achieve this.

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: Please supply some of the work you've already done

Comment: I have created a simple table in the below online editor..https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-emfcf1?file=TableComponent.js

Answer (score 0):

Just checked you code.
Adding className work fine.

```
<TableHeader className="table-header">
```

And now you can apply styling you need according to your need like

```
.table-header{
   background: #cdcdcd !important;
}

.table-header th {
   color: blue !important
}
```

[image]

This works well for changing the background color and heading color for the table!

Comment: stackblitz.com/edit/react-lmyp3b?file=TableComponent‌​.js

Comment: I tried but its not working.The tried code is https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lmyp3b?file=TableComponent.js

Comment: @joel - I've checked your snippet. It works there. Please have a look at my edited answer above. It will show you how to change the color of table heading. For that, you have to apply CSS for 'th' element. This way you can customize the styling you want.